# Why does lower interest rate result in higher debt issurance?

Tags: interest-rates, bond, debt

Is it because lower interest would reduce coupon rate since coupon rate have to be higher than the interest rate to remain attractive for debtholders?

For reference: https://marketrealist.com/2014/03/low-interest-rates-sparked-record-debt-issuance/

Comment: Yes, you got the point: lower interest rate makes debt issuance more attractive to debt issuers, because they can pay lower interest on the debt that they issue. Note that coupons don't have to be higher than the prevailing implied interest rates: for example, an issuer can issue a zero-coupon bond, with face value (say) 100$, which would then sell at a discount (say) 99. Or the coupon could be lower than the prevailing interest rates, and the security would also sell at a discount to its face value.

Comment: Thank you. Just to make sure, am I correct that this statement "lower interest rate makes debt issuance more attractive to debt issuers, because they can pay lower interest on the debt that they issue" is conditional on the debt issuance having the same discount on face value?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by debt issuance having the same discount on face value. Lower prevailing interest rates generally lower cost of borrowing.

Comment: I think I could not convey my meaning well. Maybe my question can be answered if this question is answered: Why does lower interest rate allow debt issuers to pay lower interest on the debt tey issue?

Comment: Technically, lower interest rates make the Present Value of issued debt higher, so to offer the same PV to investors, the issuer can afford to pay lower interest on the bonds they issue.

Comment: You may be overcomplicating things. The interest rate is a price (the price of borrowing). If we live in a world where i.r. are high people will do less borrowing, if they fall people will borrow more. Same as the normal reaction to any price (If the price of smartphones drop, more people buy smartphones).